# Hume's Guillotine

Tags: logic, ethics, metaethics, hume

I struggle to understand how logic doesn't validate the deduction of a moral judgement that's not present in the first premise, even if we add a second premise?

I might not be profound upon the matter, since I'm still learning and trying to understand, but if you found it boggling to understand my question, you may explain to me in detail the following text from the book '***Philosopher's Toolkit***':

> **The logical point**
>
> If you were to construct an argument taking 'Stealing Jimmy's toys upsets him' as your first (and only) premise, it would not be a logically valid argument that concluded, 'Therefore, stealing Jimmy's toys is wrong'. To make the argument valid, you would need to add a second premise:
> 'Stealing toys is wrong' or 'Upsetting Jimmy is wrong'. In both cases, you would have added something not present in your first premise – a moral judgement or prescription. The necessity of this second premise is often held to show that one cannot derive an ought from an is, or a value from a mere fact

Comment: Your opening sentence is unclear. Do you mean to ask "how does logic not validate the deduction of a moral conclusion (stealing Jimmy’s toys is wrong) from the first premise alone (stealing Jimmy’s toys upsets him)"? Replace "stealing Jimmy’s toys" with "rationing Jimmy's candy" and you will see. Just because something upsets Jimmy does not mean it is morally wrong. That is why we need the second premise to get a valid argument, and if we do add the second premise then the argument is valid. That is exactly what your quote says.

Comment: @Conifold +1 for the nice example (or should I have said the sweet example).

Comment: @Conifold, I'd upvote that as an answer.

Comment: If people were a little bit smarter, the aphorism would be "all *ought*s imply *if*'s" not "you can't get an *ought* from an *is*".

Answer (score 1):

From what I find, the nicer description is about a distinction between IS and OUGHT and how you can't really deduce an OUGHT-statement (moral judgement, prescriptive statements) from an IS-statement (description of a situation).

The point being that "ought" prescribes an action that is meant to transition the IS-state into a SHOULD-BE-state.

So if everything you produce is IS-statements, you're just... describing what is. It's like setting up a camera and let it observe. There's no judgement, no right or wrong, things just ... are. They maybe even change over time, but the camera itself has no feelings about that.

It's only when you compare the IS-state to a SHOULD-BE state that you see a discrepancy and in turn a necessity to stick to a course of action or to correct it (an OUGHT).

So in order to deduce a moral imperative you need more than just a description of what is happening, you also need an ideal, a SHOULD-BE state that acts as a moral compass allowing you to deduce what ought to happen in order to get there.

---

This is kinda relevant even today when people "turn towards science" for an answer to the question of "what should we do?".

Because science by itself CANNOT give an answer to this problem. Because the job of science is just to describe an IS state. Like a vulcano erupting is just an act of nature, it could be fascinating, beautiful, breathtaking or it could be terrifying when you're too close to it and fear that it might destroy things and people that you hold dear.

So "what should we do?" is really just an abbreviation of the question of "What should we do to achieve X?" and while everyone can agree on the question of "what should we do?" a lot of people have a lot of different ideas of what "X" should be. So what route you should take crucially depends on where you want to go, what are the things that you prioritize, what are the things that you neglect and so on.

So these aren't really questions about logic or things that you can "solve", these are questions about priorities, ideals and moral frameworks.

So the next time a "genius" thinks that A.I. will fix it, you might ask yourself "WHAT is it that they would fix?". Like it's easy to end all human suffering... Just kill humanity or put them on happy drugs. Climate change? Not a problem. The universe existed prior to it and it will exist afterwards actually earth might turn into a more interesting and vibrant planet like Venus. It's only really a problem and requires action if you think about what would happen to human shaped individuals on it's surface and whether they could keep existing in their current form or whether they would be turned into other forms of carbon like... idk ash.

The IS-state doesn't prescribe that we should do anything, it's our ideal that we'd like to keep on living in conditions that we like that urges us to do something about it.

So if people use IS-statements in order to deduce an OUGHT-statement, that's either a fallacy or there's an additional unstated premises outlining a moral framework in which this would lead to such an ought statement.

Edit: I mean you could also take your Jimmy example and look at it from the perspective of an emotionless robot, who doesn't understand the human condition. "Oh ok I understand [stealing (action)] puts [Jimmy (Person)] into [upset mode (emotional state)]" which would have the same moral implication as "pressing the switch turns the light on". In the sense that there is no moral valuation of this action, it just tells you what happens if you do something.

Answer (score -1):

I think I understand your question — and I think you are right, Hume's Guillotine makes no more sense than the example from *Philosopher’s Toolkit*. Or, strictly speaking, Hume's Guillotine makes no sense once we assume that we all share the same deterministic reality. If that assumption is true, then we can understand how this reality works, what makes us happy, and, eventually, how we can make this world a better — a happier — place. Happier for us, that is — ‘cause this is what “ought” means: Less suffering, more happiness for all.

Now why, you might ask, would David Hume propose such a nonsense? The only reason I can think of is that, again, it is only nonsense if we make certain assumption about the nature of our reality. And we cannot prove that assumption, of course, but there is a very good reason why we should make it anyway — and that reason is Hume's Guillotine. We don’t want to live in a world that we cannot make into a better place. We want to believe that we can.

As for the stealing Jimmy’s toys story as a way to explain the is-ought gap — I don’t think it makes sense no matter how you look at it. If anything, it exemplifies how far philosophy strayed from its original purpose.

> Do not take what I say as if I were merely playing. For you see, the subject of our discussion – and on what subject should a man of even slight intelligence be more serious? – namely, what kind of life one ought to live? (Socrates)